# How to disable redirect /web/xxxxxx with 2 domains on Liferay?

Tags: redirect, liferay

I am using liferay DXP 7.0 sp4. I have to handle multiple sites in a single portal instance. For e.g. I have multiple sites name as :

Name : Site1, Friendly URL : /site1

Name : Site2, Friendly URL : /site2

Name : Site3, Friendly URL : /site3

And I have 3 domains of each :

https://www.site1.com

https://www.site2.com

https://www.site3.com

Is there any such feature or property in Liferay to restrict cross site access for e.g. :

https://www.site1.com/web/site2or https://www.site1.com/web/site3

Or the only approach available is through Web Server.

Thanks & Regards,